# Google Analytics on Angular 4 not showing reports

Tags: angular, google-analytics

I have included the javascript code in the index.html file and deleted the line of

```js
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

In my app component, I have made

```js
declare const ga: any;
```

and I have put this code in the constructor

```js
  constructor(public router: Router,activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

    router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe((event:Event) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd ){
        console.log(event);
        ga('send', 'pageview', event.urlAfterRedirects);
      }
    });
  }
```

the extensions shows that the send is made.
[Tag Assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ia7QH.png) ; [GA Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnJns.png)

after all that, nothing is showing on my google analytics dashboard.

Comment: Are you checking the realtime reports in GA? The standard reports can take up to 48 hours to show you data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there was a problem in the GA configuration of the property, I made a new one, and It works perfectly !